# Python Neuron class - Name Error on a class property

Tags: python, deep-learning

I've been working on my code since yesterday and maybe I'm just tired but I'm stuck at a Name error and I can't understand why.
What I'm trying to do is make a general neuran class and then a class for each type of neuron instantiated with an appropriate method for neuron type indicator.
I'm not very fluent with classes and inheritance, maybe there's a cleaner and more Pythonic way to do it? But first why the error?:

```
class _Neuron(number, function, forwards_to=[] ):
    def __init__(self, number, function, forwards_to):
        self.number = number
        self.function = function
        self.forwards_to = forwards_to
        self.current_state = 0 #neurons may have any numeric state representing the sum of inputs from other neurons
        self.output = 0

    #whenever ready call to use up current state to calculate function output and restet the current state      
    def fire(self):
        self.output = function(self.current_state)
        self.current_state = 0
        
    #receices numeric values of outputs of other neurons and adds them to the sum of received signals   
    def receive_signal(self, input_signal):
        self.current_state+=input_signal
    
    #adds a forward connection
    def add_connection(self, neuron_number):
        if neuron_number not in self.forwards_to:
            self.forwards_to.append(neuron_number)
    #add multiple forward paths     
    def add_connections(self, **neuron_numbers):
            for neuron_number in neuron_numbers:
                self.add_connection(neuron_number)
            
    #remove a neuron connection
    def remove_connection(self, neuron_number):
        if neuron_number in self.forwards_to:
            self.forwars_to.remove(neuron_number)
    #remove multiple forward paths
    def remove_connections(self, **neuron_numbers):
            for neuron_number in neuron_numbers:
                self.remove_connection(neuron_number)
            
    def _make_deep(self):
        self.type = "deep"
        
    def _make_input(self):
        self.type = "input"
        
    def _make_output(self):
        self.type = "output"
        
    def get_number(self):
        return self.number
        
    def get_type(self):
        return self.type
        
    def get_connections(self):
        return self.forwards_to
        
    def get_current_state(self):
        return self.current_state
        
    def get_output(self):
        return self.output
        
#classes for declaring specific neuron types
#input neuron
class InputNeuron(_Neuron):
        def __init__(self, number, function, forwars_to=[]):
            super().__init__(number, function, forwars_to=[])
            self._make_input()
            
#output neuron
class OutputNeuron(_Neuron):
        def __init__(self, number, function, forwars_to=[]):
            super().__init__(number, function, forwars_to=[])
            self._make_output()
            
#deep neuron
class DeepNeuron(_Neuron):
        def __init__(self, number, function, forwars_to=[]):
            super().__init__(number, function, forwars_to=[])
            self._make_deep()
    
#tests      
f = lambda x: 1/x   
n1 = _Neuron(number=1, function=f)
n1._make_input()
n1.add_connections(1,2,3,4,5)
n1.receive_signal(100)
print(n1.get_type())
print(n1.get_number())
print(n1.get_connections())
print(n1.get_current_state())
print(n1.get_output())
n1.fire()
print(n1.get_connections())
print(n1.get_current_state())
print(n1.get_output())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see several errors:

the first to are in the init of your _Neuron class, should be something like this

- 1: your initialization parameters you need to put them in the init not when you declare the class
- 2 If you use a list as a default parameter you can have inspected result since this is declared when the class is read, and thus all instances will share the same list. Check this post for more [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43255481/python-default-list-in-function).

```py
class _Neuron:
    def __init__(self, number, function, forwards_to=None):
        if not forwards_to:
            forwards_to = []
        self.number = number
        self.function = function
        self.forwards_to = forwards_to
        self.current_state = 0 #neurons may have any numeric state representing the sum of inputs from other neurons
        self.output = 0
```

- 3 you are missing self.funtion in your method fire

```py
     def fire(self):
        self.output = self.function(self.current_state)
        self.current_state = 0
```

- 4 ** this operator is for unpacking mappers as a dictionary, you should use  a single * for list add_connections and remove_connections method

```
    def add_connections(self, *neuron_numbers):
            for neuron_number in neuron_numbers:
                self.add_connection(neuron_number)
```

5 - this is not an error but Is how I would recommend to do what you are trying. If I'm not wrong, you want to declare a base _Neuron class to inherit for the rest, that is call an abstract class, and you can use the module abc to do this. Check [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-abstract-classes-in-python-d4d2ddc02e90) to learn more about it. Note an abstract class cannot be instatiated.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class _Neuron(ABC):
    def __init__(self, number, function, forwards_to=None):
        super().__init__()
        if not forwards_to:
            forwards_to = []
        self.number = number
        self.function = function
        self.forwards_to = forwards_to
        self.current_state = 0 #neurons may have any numeric state representing the sum of inputs from other neurons
        self.output = 0
        self._make_type()

    #whenever ready call to use up current state to calculate function output and restet the current state      
    def fire(self):
        self.output = self.function(self.current_state)
        self.current_state = 0
        
    #receices numeric values of outputs of other neurons and adds them to the sum of received signals   
    def receive_signal(self, input_signal):
        self.current_state+=input_signal
    
    #adds a forward connection
    def add_connection(self, neuron_number):
        if neuron_number not in self.forwards_to:
            self.forwards_to.append(neuron_number)
    #add multiple forward paths     
    def add_connections(self, *neuron_numbers):
            for neuron_number in neuron_numbers:
                self.add_connection(neuron_number)
            
    #remove a neuron connection
    def remove_connection(self, neuron_number):
        if neuron_number in self.forwards_to:
            self.forwars_to.remove(neuron_number)
    #remove multiple forward paths
    def remove_connections(self, *neuron_numbers):
            for neuron_number in neuron_numbers:
                self.remove_connection(neuron_number)

    @abstractmethod        
    def _make_type(self):
        self.type = "deep"
        
    def get_number(self):
        return self.number
    
    def get_type(self):
        return self.type
        
    def get_connections(self):
        return self.forwards_to
        
    def get_current_state(self):
        return self.current_state
        
    def get_output(self):
        return self.output
        
#classes for declaring specific neuron types
#input neuron
class InputNeuron(_Neuron):
        def __init__(self, number, function, forwards_to=None):
            super().__init__(number, function, forwards_to=forwards_to)
        
        def _make_type(self):
            self.type = "input"
#output neuron
class OutputNeuron(_Neuron):
        def __init__(self, number, function, forwards_to=None):
            super().__init__(number, function, forwards_to=forwards_to)
        
        def _make_type(self):
            self.type = "output"
#deep neuron
class DeepNeuron(_Neuron):
        def __init__(self, number, function, forwards_to=None):
            super().__init__(number, function, forwards_to=forwards_to)
        
        def _make_type(self):
            self.type = "deep"
    
#tests      
f = lambda x: 1/x   
n1 = InputNeuron(number=1, function=f)
n1.add_connections(1,2,3,4,5)
n1.receive_signal(100)
print(n1.get_type())
print(n1.get_number())
print(n1.get_connections())
print(n1.get_current_state())
print(n1.get_output())
n1.fire()
print(n1.get_connections())
print(n1.get_current_state())
print(n1.get_output())
```

Comment: Thank you so much, these are all great tips and advice. I will need to instantiate multiple neurons in my network.

Comment: Also will the _make_type(self) be called upon instantiation of any of the 3 neuron types - deep, output, input? Or will I have to call it manually? I would like my neuralnet manager to initialize network with functions such as make_input_neurons(number_of_inputs_to_make) and use the make_input in this case.

Comment: If you check the init of the abstract class, the last of it is self. _make_type() . That makes that all neurons that inherits from the abstract one will automatically call the _make_type(self) method. Since this method is different in each other each one will call it own method

Comment: Do I understand correct - _Neuron class becomes an abstract class, meaning it's a kind of a template on which other classes can be based. And I can instantiate other classes inheriting from the _Neuron abstract class (ie DeepNeuron), but not the abstract class itself.. 
Secondly the decorator @abstractmethod means that this is a method in the abstract class that should be overwritten by definition of the inheriting class?

Comment: That is completely correct. I'm glad you got everything so fast!

Comment: It's because you explained it so well.